# How to conduct multivariate hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I have 60 samples which form 1 population. Each contain 9 variables, saying, $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, ..., X_9$, continuously ranging from 0 to 10.

Now I would like to test if there is anomaly in each sample. Abnormality here is assumed like this:
Take $X_1$, for instance. In the population, let $c$ be the $99th$ percentile value of $X_1$, in the population. In the sample, let $p$ be the percentage of example (data points) having $X_1$ value larger than or equal to $c$.
The hyposthesis test is:

$H_0: p = 1 $ (%)

$H_1: p > 1 $ (%)

There is abnormality if we reject $H_0$

The same process will be conducted with the remaining variables $X_2, X_3, X_4, ..., X_9$, which means I need to conduct 9 independent tests for each sample.

My question is: Is it possible to jointly test all 9 variables at the same time, and if so, how? I am quite new to advance statistics, so I'm not sure the name of this method (maybe multivariate testing)? If possible, could you give me some reference to a similar problem?